# Which programming language is best for the program I want to make here?

Tags: coding-style

I need a programming language with this available features:

Certainly Need:

- Option to create login/pass function
- option to 'talk' to the program
- easy to find and free to use debugger/compiler program to code in
- Option to make program respond to certain text inputs

Optional features:

- Option to save input from last use and load it up on next use
- Not have the code editable unless you own the original file
- relatively easy

Comment: See: [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the need you stated, you can go as wide a [assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), [c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_language), [c++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_language), [java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [php](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php_%28programming_language%29), [c#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck_%28programming_language%29) and much, much more. All turing complete languages can theorically fullfill all your needs.

You should ask yourself questions like compiled vs uncompiled code, local executable vs networked use and finally, if the languages you already know allow you to fullfill those too.

If you don't know any language, you should learn one before even looking toward developping a usable software. You will need to learn the low level stuff ([conditionnals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28computer_programming%29), [loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop), [variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable), etc.) and the high level stuff ([oop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), basic developments motos ([YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) for example)), then you should be able to plan and execute your development.